# Test post service jasmine karma angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I new to Unit testing and trying to run the test cases but always getting an error `Unexpected request POST service`
Below is my code

angular service

```
 angular
    .module('testModule')
    .factory('testService', testService)

  testService.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];

  function testService($q, $http){

    return {
      getAll: function(obj){
        let config = {
          headers : {
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        };

        let deferred = $q.defer();
        let payload = 'keyQueryParam=' + obj

        $http.post('url', payload, config.headers).then(response => {
          deferred.resolve(response.contents)
        })

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
  }
```

Unit test

```
describe('Test Service', function(){
    let mockTestFactory, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module('testModule');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend, _testService_){
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        mockTestFactory= _testService_;
    }));

    it('Return a POST response from a Service function', function(){
        var url = "http://localhost:3000/";
        var obj = ['ret-2','ret-5','ret-6'];
        let payload = 'keyQueryParam=' + obj

        let config = {
          headers : {
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        };

        httpBackend
            .when('POST','url', payload, function(config.headers) {
                expect(config.headers['Content-Type']).toBe('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                return config.headers['Content-Type'] === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            })
            .respond(200, { status : "success"});

        mockTestFactory.getAll(obj).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

        httpBackend.flush();
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What's `PruHTTP`? Where's this `service` url?

Comment: it was typo Updated now

Comment: if it is post then use code 201

Answer (score 0):

If your call is POST then use 201 status code as below

```
  httpBackend
    .when('POST', 'url', payload, function(config.headers) {
      expect(config.headers['Content-Type']).toBe('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      return config.headers['Content-Type'] === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    })
    .respond(201, {
      status: "success"
    });
```

Now try it should run.